# curve of x*e^(1/x) - e^((1-x^2)/x) - x - 1 on [0, +\infty[ tikz

Tags: plot

I constructed the curve of the mentioned function but it is not displayed correctly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
       xlabel=$x$,
       ylabel=$y$,
       domain=0:0.6,
       samples=100,
       axis lines=middle,
       xmin=0, xmax=0.6,
       ymin=-0.4, ymax=0.2,
       enlargelimits=true,
       xtick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6},
       ytick={-0.1,0,0.1,0.2},
       grid=both,
       width=10cm,
       height=7cm,
       ]
       \addplot[blue, ultra thick] {x*e^(1/x) - e^((1-x^2)/x) - x - 1};
       \addlegendentry{\( (\mathscr{C}_h) \)}
      \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That's what I want

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, exactly by "it is not displayed correctly." ?

Comment: @jlab When compiling my code, I have a skewed appearance of the curve.

I tried to zoom by reducing xmax and ymax but it's the same.

Comment: Yes I'll add it

Comment: Try to avoid using `^` in calculations.  For example `e^x` would be calculated as `exp{x* log(e))` where `log(e)` will be calculated using the numerical value of `e`.  Similarly `x^2` will be translated as `x*x` if you are lucky, and `exp(2*log(x))` otherwise.

Comment: Your domain start at exactly 0, where the function is undefined (and behaves badly near it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get a similar plot if you plot it on a similar domain:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
       xlabel=$x$,
       ylabel=$y$,
       domain=0.55:4,
       samples=100,
       axis lines=middle,
%       xmin=0, xmax=4,
%       ymin=-0.4, ymax=0.2,
       enlargelimits=true,
%       xtick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6},
%       ytick={-0.1,0,0.1,0.2},
       grid=both,
       width=10cm,
       height=7cm,
       ]
       \addplot[blue, ultra thick] {x*e^(1/x) - e^((1-x^2)/x) - x - 1};
%       \addlegendentry{\( (\mathscr{C}_h) \)}
      \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I would avoid setting the min/max and ticks manually, pgfplots is usually pretty good at it)